# Elixir-Is it possible to capture a key-value pair?

Tags: elixir

Having this function:

```
Enum.map(%{1 => 2, 3 => 4}, fn {k, v} -> k * v end)
```

Is it possible to capture the anonymous function? I tried to do something like this:

```
Enum.map(%{1 => 2, 3 => 4}, &*/2)
```

Or like this:

```
Enum.map(%{1 => 2, 3 => 4}, &(&1 * &2))
```

Both ways fail because the captured function has arity/2 and map is only passing 1 argument, the pair.

Is it possible to do that? It is not something that I really want to do, but I am curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a capture of one argument and then call [`Kernel.elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#elem/2) twice:

```
iex(1)> Enum.map(%{1 => 2, 3 => 4}, &(elem(&1, 0) * elem(&1, 1)))
[2, 12]
```

Answer (score 3):

One might decompose the argument with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1):

```rb
Enum.map(%{1 => 2, 3 => 4}, &(with {k, v} <- &1, do: k * v))                
#⇒ [2, 12]
```